# Openssl is either not installed properly or link to it is not working

Tags: openssl

Typing `openssl version` comes up with the following:

```
The program 'openssl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Typing `sudo apt-get install openssl` suggests it's already installed:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install openssl
[sudo] password for systemagic:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version..
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
```

Trying to locate it - I can see there is a file in `./usr/bin/openssl`

```
/$ sudo find -name "openssl"
./etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/openssl
./etc/bash_completion.d/openssl
./usr/bin/openssl
./usr/share/doc/openssl
```

Navigating to this directory it shows openssl as an archive file (red).

Please can you help get the command line working. The server has been patched and rebooted. Running `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS` and the following are present:

```
ii  libflac8:i386                               1.2.1-6                           Free Lossless Audio Codec - runtime C library
ii  libio-socket-ssl-perl                       1.53-1                            Perl module implementing object oriented interface to SSL sockets
ii  libnet-ssleay-perl                          1.42-1build1                      Perl module for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
ii  libssl0.9.8:i386                            0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1                 SSL shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.0                                 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12                 SSL shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                            1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12                 SSL shared libraries
ii  libwavpack1:i386                            4.60.1-2                          audio codec (lossy and lossless) - library
ii  openssl                                     1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12                 Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
ii  python-openssl                              0.12-1ubuntu2.1                   Python wrapper around the OpenSSL library
ii  ssl-cert                                    1.0.28ubuntu0.1                   simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

Comment: From what you show openssl is installed. Have you tried calling `/usr/bin/openssl` instead of just `openssl`? Maybe your PATH is not correctly set up.

Comment: Yes. Have tried that, thanks. End up with `/usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Then I would suggest that your system is corrupted, because things which are clearly marked as installed are not there.

Comment: If the things are corrupted and not available .better do re install  as @jkt123 suggested in the answer.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssl libssl1.0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

If your installation has been corrupted, you may be able to fix OpenSSL by reinstalling openssl and libssl like so:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssl libssl1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer. Much appreciated. I just replaced libssl1.0.0 with libssl1.1.